# How to include a 'signature' using a different font and color than the main text?

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to make something like this using LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways. The following example uses a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
APPROVED:\\[15mm]
\hline
Randell A. Hanvelt, CHAIR
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With "faked" signature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
APPROVED:\\[3mm]
\color{blue}
\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont % TeX Gyre Schola (similar to Zapf Chancery)
\Large
Randell A. Hanvelt\\[3mm]
\hline
Randell A. Hanvelt, CHAIR
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with signature]

### With font Calligra

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
APPROVED:\\[3mm]
\color{blue}
\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont
\large
Randell A. Hanvelt\\[3mm]
\hline
Randell A. Hanvelt, CHAIR
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with Calligra]

Comment: thank you but how can I add the blue name? what font is used?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. A MWE is provided by the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setromanfont{Edwardian Script ITC}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
\noindent\textsf{APPROVED:}\\[16pt]
{\addfontfeature{Scale=1.5}{\textcolor{blue}{Randell A. Hanvelt}}}\\[2pt]
\rule{9.6em}{1pt}\\
\textsf{\addfontfeature{Scale=.8}Randell A. Hanveldt, CHAIR}
\end{document}
```

to be run with XeLaTeX.